# How to model a ontology with OWL(Turtle syntax?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdflib, turtle-rdf, n3

How can I model the bold text (Villages are part of Provience)in the example below to owl using Turtle Syntax

- Turkey is made up of Provience and district
- Istanbul, Ankara, Mersin are Provience
- **Villages are part of Provience**

:Turkey rdf:type owl:class .

:Provience rdf:type owl:class .

:District rdf:type owl:class .

:Istanbul rdf:type owl:class .

:Ankara rdf:type owl:class .

:Mersin rdf:type owl:class .

:Istanbul rdfs:subClassOf owl:Turkey.

:Ankara rdfs:subClassOf owl:Turkey .

:Mersin rdfs:subClassOf owl:Turkey .

**In this section I can't decide how to do “Villages are part of Provience”** I would be very grateful if someone could give me an idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it's just RDFS, then domain and range of the property `partOf` would be appropriate. But in general I think you would need OWL here, as domain and range would make the property `partOf` restricted to only those classes

Answer (score 0):

Use as many well-known vocabularies of OWL/RDF terms as you can, rather than inventing your own.

Try [Dublin Core Terms' `isPartOf`](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/#http://purl.org/dc/terms/isPartOf) for generic part/whole relationships but you probably want something like [schema.org](https://schema.org/)'s *geoWithin*. Schema.org also has a bunch of common classes you could start with and then specialize with your specific things when you have everything working. Try this:

```
PREFIX sdo: <https://schema.org>

:Turkey a sdo:Country .

:CentralAnatolia a sdo:AdministrativeArea .

:AnkaraProvince a sdo:AdministrativeArea .

:AnkaraCity a sdo:City .

# linking
:CentralAnatolia sdo:geoWithin :Turkey .
:AnkaraProvince sdo:geoWithin :CentralAnatolia .
:AnkaraCity sdo:geoWithin :AnkaraProvince .
```